# How to test whether a page has been "pagecreated" in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I have a two page application. Both pages have all content created dynamically on the client.

Problem is, if I go `page A > page B > page A > page B`, on the second+ visit, page B does not get enhanced by Jquery Mobile anymore, although `pagecreate` triggers correctly. I'm stuck with a page of un-enhanced markup.

I can't call `create` on the separate widgets of the page, because widgets will be of random type and because I `cannot call create prior to initialization`. After receiving this error I called `pagecreate` manually on the un-enhanced page, which fixed all widgets.

Problem is, how can I detect if the page has been enhanced by JQM? Because I don't want to call this on an already enhanced page.

So, **seemingly easy question**:
How can I test if a page has been enhanced by Jquery Mobile?

Thanks for inputs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple.

1. In case you were using trigger('pagecreate') to enhance page markup then use this to check if page container has been enhanced:

   ```
   $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
       alert($.mobile.activePage.hasClass('ui-page'));
   });
   ```

   Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/HthYd/
2. In case you are using trigger('create') to enhance only page content div use this to check if content container has been enhanced:

   ```
   $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
       alert($.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role="content"]').hasClass('ui-content'));
   });
   ```

   Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8jcGb/

Of course, this cases will work only in case you are enhancing whole page or whole content.

**EDIT :**

And here's a real live example with a dynamically added page: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8jcGb/

Comment: You are quick, I also made you real live example with a dynamically added page: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8jcGb/

Comment: ah nice. I'm pulling my hair out with a page that does not get "pagecreated" by JQM. No idea why...

Comment: If you want, and if it is a simple example that you can archive, send it to my mail and I will take a look.

Comment: not simple :-) Using [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and [renderJS](http://www.renderjs.org/). If you want to take a shot, [here](http://www.franckreich.de/members/export/c/p/index.html) is a stripped down version. Click compare > go back > click compare again, this time the page does not get "created"